# OpenVPN multiple IPv4

Tags: openvpn

I have been trying to configure OpenVPN to listen on multiple IPv4 addresses. What I want to achieve is to have OpenVPN listen on all available IP address & it does it at the moment:

```
# netstat -tunlp
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1194            0.0.0.0:*                           1955/openvpn
```

But it only works on main IP address, on another IP it doesn't. I doubt it is something related to iptables. Here is how my OpenVPN configuration looks like:

```
# cat /etc/openvpn/server.conf
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
tls-auth ta.key 0
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

I installed OpenVPN using this bash script: https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install/

I would really appreciate if you can help me or give me hint of what could be wrong & how to fix it.

Thank you
Saad Ismail

Answer (score 1):

According to https://serverfault.com/a/698480/315895 you need the "multihome" option for openvpn to ensure it sends packets to clients from the correct IP (otherwise there is a very high chance they will be dropped by firewalls).